# How to reference a control in subform using a Public Sub

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a main form `frmMain` that contains a subform `C2`. `C2` has a combobox `cbo_1`. The code works fine when I put it within the subform and refer it to as `me`:

```
Me.ActiveControl.Undo
Me.cbo_1.Requery
```

However, I want to put this code in a `public sub` and would like to do the same thing. For that, I am defining `myMe` in place of `me` and rewriting the code:

```
Public myMe as Form

Set myMe = Screen.ActiveForm.C2.Form

myMe.ActiveControl.Undo
myMe.cbo_1.Requery
```

But on this, I get `Error 2467: The expression you entered refers to an object that is closed or does not exist`. Does someone know how can I fix it?

Comment: `C2` must be the name of the subform _control_. Or the active form is not the form you think it is.

Comment: You're right. I already wasted too much time in making the code generic. For now, I am just referencing the control in a traditional forms!frmMain!C2.Form.cbo_1.Requery method and it works just fine... Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to make code generic, I am now referencing the control directly :

```
frm!frmMain!C2.Form.cbo_1.Undo
frm!frmMain!C2.Form.cbo_1.Requery
```

It solves the trouble.